# Is it possible to select multiple events in the fullcalendar?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, fullcalendar-scheduler

[image]

I can't select the times I made available. In this case, it would be to select these events in green. However, it only selects where there is no event available. The only thing that works on these events in green is the fullcalendar's eventClick. I would like to select several of them.

Help!

In my project I defined selectable: true select: uncheck schedules()
However, the times are not selected in the calendar. As for the hours that do not have events on the calendar, I can select them.

Comment: `I can't select the times I made available`...these appear to be events, not available times. Events are supposed to show where there is already a booking, and the empty space shows available slots. You seem to be trying to use the calendar backwards. If you want to restrict the number of available slots, there are various ways you can do that (e.g. using Background Events and only allowing selections within those, and/or using the businessHours setting, and/or using a custom selectAllow or selectConstraint. Have a closer look at the documentation.